# Is there a way to switch interface only by interface name?

Tags: networking, ip, router, arp

I am currently working on how to switch network interface in Linux environment. And i am experimenting on switching network interface by switching default gateway, for example switch to wlan0 when eth0 is the dominant connection. What I typically do is:

```
route delete default gw 192.168.1.1 eth0
route add default gw 192.168.2.1 wlan0
```

I want to automate this process into script, but I haven't been able to find a reliable way to get wlan0's router address. Since it is not the dominating connection, netstat -rn and ip route do not give gateway address, and arp -n is not reliable to help me discriminate which IP is router's.

Is there a way to switch interface only be interface name, just like what would happen when I unplug ethernet? Or is there an alternative way to do the switch, or find router's address?

Answer (score 0):

Unless somebody else comes with an unknown tool, this can't be done in a elegant way that we both want to.

First answer, there is no way to switch the default gateway just referencing by name. The only and right way is using *route* command, like you're doing.

Second,  you can find the router just by pinging any host with a TTL's package of 1. Use *traceroute* and filter the first hop.

Use *-t* parameter of *ping* to set the time to live:

```
$ ping -t 1 192.168.0.254
```

The IP above should be your router's IP.
And *traceroute* is quite simple:

```
$ traceroute 8.8.8.8
```

What you're doing is called interface fail over and each sysadmin do it using their own Bash scripts.

Comment: Actually the `route` command has been deprecated for some time now, you should use `ip` with appropriate options for such things. You can do `ip route replace default via 192.168.2.1 dev wlan0` instead of the two `route` commands in the question. You *can* leave out the gateway, but then the system will do an ARP for *every* remote IP address it wants to reach, and the gateway system will need to proxy arp those; *not* recommended, even if it does work.

Comment: @wurtel So you are saying I can do it with: `ip route replace default via dev wlan0` ? What's the syntax for 'leave out gateway'?

Comment: @willian-paixao Can you show me 'ping any host with TTL package of 1' and how to traceroute that?

Comment: @LingyuanHe, I just edited my previous answer. Anything, let me know.